# How to set a specified positions for RadioBox and Slider steps with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button, slider

I am new with tkinter.
I am trying to make GUI and for the moment I made 3 RadioBoxe and a slider. and this what I got:

[image]

The problem that I want the 3 RadioBox to be in the same line and bellow them the slider. Is it possibe?

and I want the slider to go through odd numbers only (1,3,5,7,9 ...)

This is my code so far:

```
window = Tk()
window.title("Welcome to LikeGeeks app")

panelA = None

menu = Menu(window)
new_item = Menu(menu)
new_item.add_command(label='Open File', command=open_file)
new_item.add_separator()
new_item.add_command(label='Save File')
new_item.add_separator()
new_item.add_command(label='Exit')
menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=new_item)
window.config(menu=menu)

label_blur = Label(window, text="Blurring")
label_blur.pack(anchor="w", padx=10, pady=10)
blur_rad1 = Radiobutton(window, text='Average', value=0)
blur_rad2 = Radiobutton(window, text='Gaussian', value=1)
blur_rad3 = Radiobutton(window, text='Median', value=2)
blur_rad1.pack(anchor="w", padx=10, pady=0)
blur_rad2.pack(anchor="w", padx=10, pady=0)
blur_rad3.pack(anchor="w", padx=10, pady=0)
blur_slide = Scale(window, from_=1, to=31, length=600,tickinterval=5, orient=HORIZONTAL)
blur_slide.pack(anchor="w", padx=10, pady=10)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: @stovfl: No my issue is the layout, the RadioBox is easy to fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two simple solutions: use `grid` so that you can specify the row and columns, or continue to use `pack`, but place the radiobuttons in a separate frame.

Since you're already using pack, it's easiest to use the second method.

Create a frame for the buttons, and use `pack` to add it to the window where you want it to appear:

```
button_frame = Frame(window)
button_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")
```

Make the buttons children of the frame:

```
blur_rad1 = Radiobutton(button_frame, ...)
blur_rad2 = Radiobutton(button_frame, ...)
blur_rad3 = Radiobutton(button_frame, ...)
```

Use `pack` to lay out the buttons left-to-right:

```
blur_rad1.pack(side="left", expand=True)
blur_rad2.pack(side="left", expand=True)
blur_rad3.pack(side="left", expand=True)
```